# Why do I get "AssertionError: May not set both `read_only` and `required`" in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Why am I getting **`AssertionError: May not set both 'read_only' and 'required'`** when I try to access the `TestViewSet`?

Here is the MRE:

models.py:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)

class Test(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    foo = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('channel_id', 'foo'),
        )
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers, viewsets, serializers

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = [
            'channel_id',
            'foo',
        ]

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('test', TestViewSet)
```

If you remove the unique constraint on `Test`, or set `fields='__all__'`, on the serializer, the view magically starts working again.

I'd prefer not to use `fields='__all__'` for 2 reasons:

- it will result in a lot of unused data on my real serializer
- the `channel_id` column ends up being rendered as `channel`, which is inconvenient, and will force me to update my frontend code to reference `channel`, or I will have to append `_id` to the data.

I would just create an alias on the serializer:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel_id = serializers.CharField(source='channel_id')
    
    ...
```

but doing so results in another error...

```
AssertionError: It is redundant to specify `source='channel_id'` on field 'CharField' in serializer 
'OrderSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.
```

TLDR;

How can I render the `channel` foreign key as `channel_id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare **`channel_id`** explicitly

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channel_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['channel_id', 'foo', ]
```

If you wish to change the return type of `channel_id` to a string, then you can use **`serializers.CharField`** instead of `serializers.IntegerField`

Comment: Technically, it should be `IntegerField()`, since FKs do not store their values as strings @Elrond Supports Monica